# android recyclerView firebase

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Buenas Tardes, estoy desarrollando una app con tabs y fragments,El problema que tengo es que al iniciar la app el recyclerView que esta dentro de una fragment no me muestra nada al principio,pero si  me muevo hacia el ultimo tabs y vuelvo al tab que tiene el recyclerView recién ahi es como que reacciona ,Les envío el código  para ver si me pueden ayudar

Este es el que carga los tabs y los fragments

```
    package com.example.juego.frasear.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.juego.frasear.R;
import com.example.juego.frasear.adapters.adapterPrincipal;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.homeFragment;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.jugadoresFragment;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.perfilFragment;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.rankingFragment;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

/**
 * Created by franco on 26/08/16.
 */
public class principal extends AppCompatActivity {






    private Toolbar toolbar,toolbarJugadores,toolbarMiPerfil;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TextView toolbar_title,toolbarJug_title,
            toolbarMiPerfil_title;
    //  that will host the section contents.
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Typeface font_roboto_light,font_bigboss,font_frase_menu,font_gametime;
    String email_usuario;
    //controlador c=new controlador();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        font_gametime = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Game_Time.ttf");
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //toolbar.setTitle("Frasear");
        toolbar_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbar_title.setTypeface(font_gametime);
        toolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user==null)
        {
            irAlogin();
        }
        if(user!=null) {

           // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the activity.
            // sectionsPagerAdapter that is used as the adapter for a ViewPager.

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
     //      viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerChangeListener());

            setupViewPager(viewPager);


            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            // tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            setupTabIcons();

        }
    }  // fin oncreate

    private void irAlogin()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_home, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_jugadores, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_ranking, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

        TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

        tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_perfil, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapterPrincipal adapter = new adapterPrincipal(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //ViewPagerAdapter adapter =new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new homeFragment(),"HOME" );
        adapter.addFragment(new jugadoresFragment(), "PLAYERS");
        adapter.addFragment(new rankingFragment(), "RANKING");
        adapter.addFragment(new perfilFragment(), "PERFIL");
        // mostrarToolbarsHome();
        //adapter.esconderToolbars();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




   /* public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerChangeListener() {
        return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                if(tabLayout.getTabAt(1).isSelected()) {
                    jugadoresFragment j =new jugadoresFragment();

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

               if(tabLayout.getTabAt(1).isSelected()) {

                   jugadoresFragment j =new jugadoresFragment();


               }

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        };

    }*/


  /*  public void mostrarToolbarsHome() {
       toolbarJugadores.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbarMiPerfil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void mostrarToolbarsJugadores()
    {
        toolbarJugadores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbarMiPerfil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    public void mostrarToolbarMiPerfil()
    {
        toolbarMiPerfil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbarJugadores.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


*/
}
```

Luego tenemos el fragment del recyclerView

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.juego.frasear.R;
import com.example.juego.frasear.adapters.recyclerAdapter;
import com.example.juego.frasear.models.controlador;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by franco on 27/08/16.
 */
public class jugadoresFragment extends Fragment {

    FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   //ArrayAdapter<String> adaptadorListaAmigos;
     controlador c;
    //principal p;
   // DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ArrayList<String> listaNombres;
    ArrayList<String> listaUrl;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //DataSnapshot data;
    //private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;



    public jugadoresFragment() {
        c=new controlador();
        // Required empty public constructor
        //c.getNombreAsyncronicos();




}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listaNombres=c.getAmigosNombres(user.getEmail());
        listaUrl=c.getAmigosUrl(user.getEmail());
        String hola="hola";
    //leadsNames=c.getAmigos();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jugadores, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
            llmanager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llmanager);


            recyclerAdapter myAdapter = new recyclerAdapter(v.getContext(),listaNombres,listaUrl);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        return v;
    }


    }
```

Luego la clase del recyclerView

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.juego.frasear.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.CropCircleTransformation;

/**
 * Created by franco on 12/09/16.
 */
public class recyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> imagenes;

    public recyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items,ArrayList<String> imagenes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items= items;
        this.imagenes=imagenes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder itemsViewHolder, int i) {
        itemsViewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(i));;
        Glide.with(this.context).load(imagenes.get(i))
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(context))
                .into(itemsViewHolder.vImagen);

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Campos de la lista
        public TextView vTitle;
       public ImageView vImagen;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            vImagen= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenAmigos);
        }
    }

}
```

Luego tengo la clase controlador

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.models;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.example.juego.frasear.databases.catalogo_amigos;
import com.example.juego.frasear.databases.catalogo_asynco;
import com.example.juego.frasear.databases.catalogo_usuarios;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

/**
 * Created by franco on 06/09/16.
 */
public class controlador {

    public boolean guardarUsuario(jugador jug)  {
        catalogo_usuarios cat=new catalogo_usuarios();
       boolean rta=cat.guardarUsuario(jug);
        return rta;
    }

    /*public void buscarUsuario()
    {
        catalogo_usuarios cat= new catalogo_usuarios();
        cat.buscarUsuario();

    }*/

   public ArrayList<String> getAmigosNombres(String email)
    {
        catalogo_amigos cat=new catalogo_amigos();
        ArrayList<String> rtas=cat.getAmigosNombres(email);
        //String hola="asdsa";
        return rtas;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAmigosUrl(String email)
    {
        catalogo_amigos cat=new catalogo_amigos();
        ArrayList<String> rtas=cat.getAmigosUrl(email);
        return rtas;
    }

    public void guardarAmigos(ArrayList<amigo> listaAmigos,String email)
    {
        catalogo_amigos cat=new catalogo_amigos();
        cat.guardarAmigos(listaAmigos,email);
    }

    public void getNombreAsyncronicos()
    {
        catalogo_asynco a=new catalogo_asynco();
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> array=a.execute("fml_z@hotmail.com");
        try {
            ArrayList<String> as= array.get();
            String hola="hola";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

luego  tengo la clase catalogo_amigos que es donde hace la interaccion con firebase

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.databases;

import android.os.Handler;

import com.example.juego.frasear.models.amigo;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by franco on 16/09/16.
 */
public class catalogo_amigos  {

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ArrayList<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listaUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    Long nro;
    Handler mhandler,mhandler1;


    public catalogo_amigos()
    {
            mhandler=new Handler();
            mhandler1=new Handler();

    }


    public void guardarAmigos(ArrayList<amigo> lista, String email) {
        ArrayList<String> lista_name = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> lista_url = new ArrayList<>();
        String delimitadores = "@";
        String[] emailCortado = email.split(delimitadores);
       /*for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
        {
            amigo a=lista.get(i);
            lista_name.add(i,a.getName());
        }
        //String nro=String.valueOf(i);
        DatabaseReference amig = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);;
        amig.setValue(lista_name);
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
        {
            amigo a=lista.get(i);
            lista_url.add(i,a.getUrl());
        }
        DatabaseReference url = ref.child("imagenes_amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
        url.setValue(lista_url);
*/
        DatabaseReference am = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
        am.setValue(lista);

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getAmigosNombres(final String email) {


                //Aquí ejecutamos nuestras tareas costosas


        String delimitadores = "@";
        String[] emailCortado = email.split(delimitadores);
        DatabaseReference amigos = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
        amigos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> radiatosIterator = i.iterator();
                while (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot c = radiatosIterator.next().child("name");
                    String name = c.getValue(String.class);
                    listaNombres.add(name);

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

        return listaNombres;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAmigosUrl(final String email) {


        mhandler1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String delimitadores = "@";
                String[] emailCortado = email.split(delimitadores);
                DatabaseReference amigos = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
                amigos.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                        Iterator<DataSnapshot> radiatosIterator = i.iterator();
                        while (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
                            DataSnapshot c = radiatosIterator.next().child("url");
                            String url = c.getValue(String.class);
                            listaUrl.add(url);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            });

        return listaUrl;
    }

}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, espero su respuesta.

Comment: Ya elimine el otro post y deje este

Answer (score 1):

En Android haveces también me pasa ese problema, al crear el Viewpager nos pide un context y como el viewpager esta dentro de un fragmento del tab tenemos que poner el **getSupportFragmentManager();** Pero despues en dicho fragmento tenemos el ReciclerView y al crearlo tambien nos pide un context como estamos dentro de otro fragmento no podemos usar el Context de la Actividad si no tenemos que usar el del fragmento por tanto se tiene que hacer de esta manera.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo pero lo solucione en esta linea que tiene:

```
LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
```

Lo cambie por LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new

```
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

//getActivity() obtiene el contexto de la activity ya que el fragmen no tiene su propio contexto.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto simplemente define el contexto de la Activity pero como ayudaría a mostrar el contendido como indica la pregunta?